# Deployed ASP.NET MVC 3.0 only works with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Today I have been battling with a very odd issue. I spend my days developing an ASP.NET MVC3 web application that used to be ASP.NET 4. It not is now half MVC3 and half ASP.NET 4 all running under the same application. This is all fine.

Today we set up a brand new staging environment (Server 2008 R2), deployed the code and ran the app. Only to get HTTP 404 errors when trying to access any MVC page, all aspx pages worked fine. To prove that the issue was environmental we deployed the same code to a new application on the development box and this worked without a hitch.

After spending all day making sure both environments were exactly the same (IIS Role Services, Windows Updates, Installed Applications.. everything) I then noticed on the 404 error page that the Handler for the request was "StaticFile".

After a bit of googling I came across the option in the title

```
<system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules></system.webServer>
```

This now works, so I assume the modules used for none static routes isn't being called without it (forgive me if I’m being naive).

The thing is, on our development environment, the web.config doesn't have this attribute.

So why does it work without it on one server and not on another. Surely its less efficient to be calling all modules for all requests.

If anyone has any idea's to why this might be happening I would be eternally grateful, as although our staging environment now works, i hate not knowing exactly thy.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would check is to ensure that the following update is applied to your new brand new staging environment as it may have already been applied to your existing development environment and would explain why one environment is working and one is not:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

For more information about static file routing, the hotfix above and general "how does extensionless routing" work, I recommend reading the following article:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Comment: installing that hotfix did the trick, thank you. however what is odd, is that our dev box doesn't have this hotfix installed yet still works!?

Comment: I am not sure how to address this, since they are not exact duplicate environments, it could be a minor IIS version difference, some other windows update component, etc.  Without knowing the exact setups, it is hard to say.  Glad this worked for you!